# Can I mount an ISO without administrative privileges?

Tags: mount, cd

Can I mount an ISO in Ubuntu 10.04 without requiring the use of sudo?

This is all I know how to do:

```
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 image.iso /media/iso
```

---

A few answers mentioned using something called "Archive Mounter". I've never noticed this before, but I do see it listed in the "Open With" list when right-clicking ISO files.

Where can I find documentation on how to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an option to "Open With..." when I right click on an ISO with an "Archive Mounter".

This executes `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-archive` which then mounts the ISO automatically. It's part of gvfs, which is installed by default. I am not sure if Nautilus is set to use it by default. (If someone can clarify in a comment I'll update this)

To set it as an option as a default double click, right click on the ISO, select Properties and navigate to this tab and select the radio button to make use of it:

[image]

If it's not available as an option click Add and then select it from the list of applications, then you can go back to the tab and select it as a default action if hat's what you want. If you only use it on occasion having it in the Open With tab will have it show up when you right-click and Open With...

Comment: What should I expect to happen when I open an ISO with Archive Mounter? I don't see any change in the output of `mount` after running this.

Comment: @Ændrük, When you open an .iso with archive mounter the iso should pop in to the left-side bar in the file manager, and as Javier says in another comment the "cd" is accessible from within the .gvfs folder in you home directory.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. On my system nothing happens at all when I use Archive Mounter; nothing appears within ~/.gvfs. With no documentation available, I had no way of knowing whether something was broken. Now that I know there is a problem I will pursue the issue on Launchpad.

Comment: Good idea, this looks like a bug.

Comment: @Source Lab: Archive Mounter works only with regular ISO images. No mixed data, multi-tracks. Maybe thats the reason it didnt work for you. Have you tried other images?

Comment: Now `gio mount` replace `gvfs-mount`. Could you update how would it be? To mount an iso on the terminal with `gio`.

Answer (score 10):

To mount an ISO without administrator privileges you can use `fuseiso`:

```
fuseiso image.iso ~/mountdir
```

Unmount the image using `fusermount`:

```
fusermount -u ~/mountdir
```

If you don't have `fuseiso` you will have to install it from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install fuseiso
```

You will need administrator privileges to install.

Comment: you need to add the user to the "fuse group": sudo gpasswd -a <span style="font-weight:bold;">yourusername</span> fuse

Comment: @Axel: or use the Users and Groups GUI... checking the "Mount user-spadc filesystems (FUSE)" checkbox in the User Privileges tab

Answer (score 0):

I think he means an alternative to mount -o loop?

- Archive Mounter (default)
- Furius ISO mount
- Acetone ISO

CD-Rom should work for users by default

Comment: Can you explain a little more about Archive Mounter? What package is it installed from?

Comment: I think it's installed by default. On my Ubuntu 10.10 fresh installation, the default action for ISO-Files is to mount them. I think it should be in the file-roller package, but I'm not shure.

Answer (score -1):

The functionality you ask for should be perfectly covered by `pmount` ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmount)).  In your case, the following command:

```
pmount -o loop -t iso9660 image.iso iso
```

should mount your image.iso under /media/iso

EDIT: this doesn't work, as pmount has no "-o" option

Comment: Unfortunately, pmount doesn't accept the options that mount does, so you cannot specify '-o loop'.