# Apps capable of mounting/unmounting CD/DVD Images with multi-sector or protected format

Tags: software-recommendation, mount, cd-image

What apps for Ubuntu exist that can mount/unmount CD/DVD images. Image formats like cue, bin, iso, nero format, etc...

Needed features:

- Emulate protected CD/DVD like Daemon-Tools
- Mount multi-sector images
- Converting other formats (including multi-sector images) to ISO format.

UPDATE - Updated question to "need the 3 features above instead of having them as optional". This 3 features are needed to be able to use images that have any of this features enable.

For normal mounting/burning image apps you can see here:

[How can I graphically mount ISOs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43469/how-can-i-graphically-mount-isos)

[Can I mount an ISO without administrative privileges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4140/can-i-mount-an-iso-without-administrative-privileges)

[How to burn or mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see you have the same problem as I have and I found the solution and want to share it with you. The name of the app is **cdemu** you can install by doing the following steps in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cdemu/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcdemu
```

(Or open Synaptic and type **cdemu** in the search box)

([Source Info](http://www.chw.net/foro/gnu-linux-y-otros-sistemas-operativos-f18/983552-cdemu-equivalente-daemon-tools-en-linux.html))

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am looking for an ISO image to test.

Comment: I accepted because it actually opened the image with no problem at all, specially the part about multi-sector. But since the game did not work (Maybe it was wine or the image) I could not test the game out. Anyway, the program did do what I asked.

Comment: Ok a year has passed I can confirm this is the best app for any kind of image file related to ISO, NRG, CUE, BIN and well, it is basically like Daemon Tools. It has opened images that any other apps could not and I am including even apps like Furious ISO and Acetone2iso. Even the mount command does not do all the stuff this app does and to top it, it actually mounts and dismounts correctly with Nautilus. No issues like leaving a mounted unit opened. Works perfect.

Comment: Now the app name is ˙gcdemu˙ and contrary to no longer updated nrg2iso it mounts my new NRG images! Great! Please update the install line above to `sudo apt-get install gcdemu`